# Stop input from JavaBean

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I'm currently building a web game which takes input from user, places the data in a javabean, and then updates the board and checks for a winner. I'm able to send out a winner message correctly, but my question is how could I halt the flow of input once a winner has been determined, so that the board stays the same (until new game is clicked)?

My input is coming in via a setmoveCol(String movecol) method. I'd like to check if input is coming in after a winner has been determined, print a relative "Game is over Message", and deny the move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are possibly a lot of ways but one way could be:

- You could set a boolean when a winner is found and ignore any input if that boolean is true

if you want to have more detailed synchronisation oportunities:

- You could remember a timestamp when the winner is found, and if anyone inputs something you should also get a timestamp for that action. So you can ignore any input which timestamp is higher than the timestamp of the winner.

Comment: The first option sounds good to me; my main concern here is how I would stop input once that condition is met.